# Menu jumps after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The problem is my menu jumps when new page is loaded (the selected menu item should be perfectly centred. The menu uses the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    /* Menu klik animatie II */
    $("nav#menu a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var dit = $(this);
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current_page_item");
        $(this).parent().addClass("current_page_item");
        geselecteerd = $('#menu li.current_page_item').sumOuterWidth(true);
        voor = $('#menu li.current_page_item').prevAll().sumOuterWidth(true);
        vader = $('#menu').parent().width();
        invoegen = parseInt(((vader-geselecteerd)/2)-voor);
        $('nav#menu').prev().animate({
            width: invoegen + 'px',
        }, {
            duration: 400,
            specialEasing: {
                width: 'linear',
                height: 'easeOutBounce'
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#content').fadeTo('fast', 0.01, function() {
                document.location = $(dit).attr('href');
            });
        }
      });
    });

    /* Menu uitlijning: geselecteerde item centraal */
    $.fn.sumOuterWidth = function(useMargins) {
      var sum = 0;
      this.each(function() { 
        sum += $(this).outerWidth(useMargins);
      });
      return sum;
    };

    geselecteerd = $('#menu li.current_page_item').sumOuterWidth(true);
    voor = $('#menu li.current_page_item').prevAll().sumOuterWidth(true);
    vader = $('#menu').parent().width();
    invoegen = parseInt(((vader-geselecteerd)/2)-voor);
    $('#menu').before("<div style='width:" + invoegen + "px;float:left'>&nbsp;</div>");
});
```

I can't really think what I did wrong; the width (from the div before the menu) should be the same on the animated one (before new page is loaded) and on the new loaded page.
Anybody an idea about this?

When I use a different font (Varela Round -> Google web fonts) it doesn't happen.

Comment: maybe try wrapping this around your code? $(window).load(function() { //code });

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery syntax runs the code when the DOM is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ }
```

In certain cases you'll want the whole page (and it's image dependencies) to be loaded before your code runs. In those cases us the following:

```
$(window).load(function() { //code })
```

Comment: Calling script at the end of body tag also will solve problem i hope